# select in JPA returning null value

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I just need some specific columns of the entity, I'm trying to get with a DTO that I created only what is necessary, it returns the right amount of records but all data is null.

Query:

```
"Select n from DocumentoFiscalEntity n"
```

Method:

```
 public List<MovimentoLojaDTO> buscarTeste(){
    
    List<DocumentoFiscalEntity> list = manager.createNamedQuery("testeNovo", DocumentoFiscalEntity.class).getResultList();
    List<MovimentoLojaDTO> dtoList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DocumentoFiscalEntity entity : list){
        dtoList.add(new MovimentoLojaDTO(entity.getIdDocumento(),entity.getDtEntrada(), entity.getVlDocumentoFiscal(), entity.getOperacao()));
    }
    return dtoList;
}
```

Json return:
[null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Brp.png)

Comment: Did you inspect that `dtoList` variable at the return line?
How and where is this JSON generated?

Comment: in debug mode the list brings 14 results and the dtoList does not receive the data, only the record number

Comment: If `list`returns 14 records your problem isn't about JPA, it is working fine. Your problem is more likely related to the framework your are using to convert it to JSON or something in the middle. How are you generating your JSON? I would also recommend you to make a temp method that calls the `buscarTeste()` method in order to inspect the return of this method to make sure your DTO transformation is fine.

Comment: Post the `DocumentoFiscalEntity` code if possible.